# Count ID Where SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a CalendarDates Table that go

```
Year Month MonthName Date
2017   1     Jan     2017-01-01 
2017   1     Jan     2017-01-02   ect
```

I have companydetails table,  IDs that are registered customers..

COLUMNS AS:
    ID
    JoinedCompanyDate
    LeftCompanyDate  (this can be null if customer still remains joined to company)

dates formatted as example 2014-07-30 00:00:00.000

I need to write a `count(ID)`, of customers per month for e.g 2017-01-01 (start of each month) firstly WithTheCompany, and how many have LeftTheCompany

I have tried to count with

```
Count (case when example.. with no joy
```

and

```
Count (ID where example does not seem to work
```

Any ideas team?

Please help

Comment: Edi the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: Are the shown dates YYYYMMDD or YYYYDDMM?

Comment: dates are formatted 2014-07-30 00:00:00.000

Comment: I would urge you to read your post and ask yourself if you would be able to provide an answer, or even understand what is being asked, based solely on the information provided. We can't see your screen or read your mind. Give us some information. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Could you give a different name for that `date` table? It's not recommended to use a reserved word as the name for a column or a table. Also, what's the relevance of that table?

Comment: I have added the table calendardates as requested. it just my way of linking the  companydetails to a first of the month column. I just need something like  2017-01-01  Total  Left ...2017-02-01  Total  Left

Answer (score 0):

I am going to have to make an assumption, because of the mess your explanation of date formats is (20170201, 20170301 etc are completely useless without explanation: are they 1 Feb and 1 Mar or are they 2 Jan and 3 Jan? They certainly aren't formatted 2014-07-30 00:00:00).

I am assuming that the underlying datatype in the database is a Date or DateTime. This is not actually stored in any 'format' which looks anything like a date: utilities (like SSMS) choose to present them however they are programmed to: for SSMS it is in YYYY-MM-DD HH-mm-ss.s format. If this assumption is incorrect and they are stored as some type of char (or vachar or nvarchar) then your first step is to change them to Date or DateTime; dates not stored as Date types always lead to tears.

Your explanation of what you require as output is also a bit unclear. I am assuming that you want the total number of existing customer at the start of a month, and the number of customers who stopped being customers in the previous month. This may not be correct, but that's what I'm assuming.

A query like the following:

```
select 'Total' as 'Desc', count(*) as [count]
from tablename 
where JoinedCompaanyDate < '2018-08-1'
and LeftCompanyDate is null
union
select 'Left', count(*)
from tablename
where LeftCompanyDate >= '2018-07-1'
and LeftCompanyDate < '2018-08-1'
```

will give:

```
Desc    Count    
Total   500    
Left    75
```

..showing 500 existing customers at the start of 1st Aug 2018, with 75 leaving during the previous month.

You could wrap tat query in a Pivot to get something like:

```
Total  Left    
500    75
```

If you wish to do that, please ask a new question.

Comment: sorry its a habit from writing the query language e.g where date = '20170101'

Comment: Hi works great, but how does this join to a column showing total for each month as a column please? kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like a full join of the total joiners and total leavers on the year and month.

**Example:**

```
-- Table variable for easy testing
declare @YourTable table (id int identity(1,1) primary key, JoinedCompanyDate datetime, LeftCompanyDate datetime);
-- Sample data
insert into @YourTable (JoinedCompanyDate, LeftCompanyDate) values
('2017-01-01T00:00:00', null),
('2017-01-02T00:00:00', '2017-01-02T00:00:00'), 
('2017-02-01T00:00:00', null),
('2017-02-02T00:00:00', '2017-02-03T00:00:00'), 
('2017-02-01T00:00:00', '2017-03-01T00:00:00'),
('2017-04-01T00:00:00', null);

-- Query
SELECT 
 COALESCE(Joiners.YearMonth, Leavers.YearMonth) AS YearMonth, 
 ISNULL(Joiners.Total,0) AS TotalJoined, 
 ISNULL(Leavers.Total,0) AS TotalLeft,
 SUM(ISNULL(Joiners.Total,0) - ISNULL(Leavers.Total,0)) OVER (ORDER BY COALESCE(Joiners.YearMonth, Leavers.YearMonth)) AS CumSumTotals
FROM
(
  SELECT 
   (YEAR(JoinedCompanyDate) * 100) +
   MONTH(JoinedCompanyDate) AS YearMonth,
   COUNT(*) AS Total
  FROM @YourTable
  WHERE JoinedCompanyDate IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY YEAR(JoinedCompanyDate), MONTH(JoinedCompanyDate)
) AS Joiners
FULL JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
   (YEAR(LeftCompanyDate) *100) +
   MONTH(LeftCompanyDate) AS YearMonth,
   COUNT(*) AS Total
  FROM @YourTable
  WHERE LeftCompanyDate IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY YEAR(LeftCompanyDate), MONTH(LeftCompanyDate)
) AS Leavers
ON Joiners.YearMonth = Leavers.YearMonth;
```

Comment: Hi This code is having issues. it says there is issues with the section FROM JoinedCompanyDate) * 100)

Comment: @pete  Isn't `JoinedCompanyDate` just a column?  Well, I've changed the `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ...)` to `YEAR(...)`, and the same thing for the month. So try again.